# AWS SNS: Edit text messaging preferences

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I am trying to enable SMS message delivery logs in AWS SNS. But no matter what I do I get this error:

```
Couldn't set text messaging attributes. Error code: AuthorizationError
- Error message: You are not authorized to perform actions for the provided bucket
```

I have tried numerous IAM roles (including admin access role) and I am logged in as the root account owner.

What might I be missing? What can I try?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you set the bucket policy to allow the SNS role to write to it?

Comment: The bucket was auto generated by AWS so I assumed with the right permissions. However changing the bucket policy to allow all S3 actions I was able to save the settings. Thank you...

Answer (score 6):

I found this specific documentation that solved it for me: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html#example_bucket_policy

The key is that the bucket policy needs to list `sns.amazonaws.com` as the principal, and really only needs to allow these 3 actions to finish configuring SMS:

- s3:GetBucketLocation
- s3:ListBucket
- s3:PutObject

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thank you so much. Just change the bucket name to your bucket name.

Answer (score 3):

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1653549854620",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Stmt1653549853470",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME"
}
]
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).